# SQL Server 2008 collation arabic

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, collation

We are currently having a problem loading arabic into a SQL Server 2008 database.

We want to load
بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِ

but in the database it changes to

بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَ?نِ الرَّحِيمِ

with a ? added,

We have set the collation `Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS` and `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1256_CS_AS`

and neither of these work..... any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a quick test this end none of the built in collations can represent all characters in that string in a single byte code page so you would need to use a unicode datatype.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @StringToTest nvarchar(2047) = N'بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِ'

--The below without the problematic character returns 7 results
--DECLARE @StringToTest nvarchar(2047) = N'بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَنِ الرَّحِيمِ'


CREATE TABLE #Results
(
name sysname
)

CREATE TABLE #Chars(
C NCHAR(1)
)
INSERT INTO #Chars
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(@StringToTest,number,1)
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type='P' AND number BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(@StringToTest)


CREATE TABLE #Collations
(
     code TINYINT PRIMARY KEY
);

WITH E00(N) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),   --2
        E02(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E00 a, E00 b), --4
        E04(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E02 a, E02 b), --16
        E08(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E04 a, E04 b) --256
INSERT INTO #Collations
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) - 1
FROM E08    

DECLARE @AlterScript NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @AlterScript = @AlterScript + ' 
RAISERROR(''Processing' + name + ''',0,1) WITH NOWAIT;
ALTER TABLE #Collations ADD ' + name + ' CHAR(1) COLLATE ' + name + ';
EXEC(''UPDATE #Collations SET ' + name + '=CAST(code AS BINARY(1))'');
EXEC(''UPDATE #Collations SET ' + name + '=NULL WHERE ASCII(' + name + ') <> code'');
EXEC(''
IF NOT EXISTS(
SELECT *
FROM #Chars
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #Collations WHERE ' + name + ' = C COLLATE ' + name + '))
INSERT INTO #Results
SELECT ''''' + name + '''''
'');
'
FROM   sys.fn_helpcollations()
WHERE  name LIKE '%CS_AS'
       AND name NOT IN    /*Unicode Only Collations*/
                        ( 'Assamese_100_CS_AS', 'Bengali_100_CS_AS',
                         'Divehi_90_CS_AS', 'Divehi_100_CS_AS' ,
                         'Indic_General_90_CS_AS', 'Indic_General_100_CS_AS',
                             'Khmer_100_CS_AS', 'Lao_100_CS_AS',
                         'Maltese_100_CS_AS', 'Maori_100_CS_AS',
                         'Nepali_100_CS_AS', 'Pashto_100_CS_AS',
                         'Syriac_90_CS_AS', 'Syriac_100_CS_AS',
                         'Tibetan_100_CS_AS' )


EXEC (@AlterScript)


SELECT * FROM #Results

DROP TABLE #Collations
DROP TABLE #Results
DROP TABLE #Chars
```

Comment: It probably does quite a bit more than strictly necessary. [I had previously written some code to see the characters supported in all the collation families here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180764/sql-server-code-pages-and-collations/5206519#5206519) and I just re-purposed it for this question. There may well be simpler ways of running through all the collations to test which ones won't mangle any of the characters in a string.

Answer (score 1):

I use `utf8_bin` to store Arabic in MySQL. If you have that option for MSSQL I would try using that. You should also make sure that your application isn't the cause of the offending character.